# Trying to calculate time and storage complexity for a function (C)

Tags: c, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

edit: I figured out how to properly calculate the time complexity but still can't figure out the storage complexity.

edit:figured everything out.

I tried solving a complexity question and failed.

The answer should be : time complexity - n(m+n), storage complexity - m+n.

Please help me understand where I am wrong and suggest a way to understand/solve these types of questions better.

Here is the function:

```
void f(int n, int m){
     if (n <= 1) {
         int *arr=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
         for (int i=0; i<m; i++) arr[i] = 0;
         free(arr);
         return;
     }
     f(n-1, m+1);
     f(n%2, m+1);
}
```

From what I see "free(arr)" frees the memory that malloc allocates, which makes malloc irelavent in terms of time complexity.
edit: someone explained me that even though we use 'free' the malloc is still taken into consideration (space cpmlexity wise).

I see that the first function call makes the function call itself n times and when that happens m is incramented by 1 - n times, so the time complexity for the first func call is n(m+1) and the storage complexity n- since there are n calls to the function in recursion. edit: figured it out eventually.

The second function call calls the function log(n) times and m is incremented log(n) times which makes the time complexity for this call : log(n)(m+1).
Storage complexity:log(n).

So total time complexity is n(m+1), total storage complexity is n.

Comment: Please do not include code as picture. You should post it here.

Comment: It is from a picture but I will type it myself and post here.

Comment: The problem here is the presence of a crappily-written recursive function, which cannot be trivially optimized. It needs to be manually replaced by a loop - discussing performance of bad code is pretty meaningless.

Comment: "even though we use 'free' the malloc is still taken into consideration (space cpmlexity wise)."  Many implementations do not actually allocate any memory during the malloc call, but instead when the memory is used the first time. So ask "someone" what they meant and which system they had in mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
void f(int n, int m){
     if (n <= 1) {
         int *arr=malloc(m*sizeof(int));
         for (int i=0; i<m; i++) arr[i] = 0;
         free(arr);
         return;
     }
     f(n-1, m+1);
     f(n%2, m+1);
}
```

Let's refactor it:

```
void f1(int m) {
    int *arr = malloc(m*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        arr[i] = 0;
    }
    free(arr);
}

void f(int n, int m){
     if (n <= 1) {
         f1(m);
         return;
     }
     f(n-1, m+1);
     f(n%2, m+1);
}
```

So for f1 it's quite simple, - space complexity is `sizeof(int) * m` - we need to allocate that much - and time complexity is just `m` - we are looping through all the `m` elements in the array `arr`.

The `n%2` can only be `1` or `0`, so we can substitute the `f(n%2, m+1);` for `f1(m+1)`.

```
void f(int n, int m){

     if (n <= 1) {
         f1(m); // (1)
         return;
     }

     f(n-1, m+1); // (2)

     f1(m + 1); // (3)
}
```

Now. If `n > 1` then we call `f(n-1, ...` until `n <= 1`. For each `n > 1` we call `f1(m + 1)` in the reverse chronological order (because it's after the recursive call). When we get to `n <= 1` then `f1(m)` is called with `m = m(initial) + n(initial) - 1` times. 
Och, maybe an example for example for `n=5`, then:

- initial call to `f(5, m)` so n=5
- n=5, so we call `f(4, m+1)` // (2)
- n=4, so we call `f(3, m+2)` // (2)
- n=3, so we call `f(2, m+3)` // (2)
- n=2, so we call `f(1, m+4)` // (2)
- n=1, so we call `f1(m+4)` and return // (1)
- n=2, after (2), so we call `f1(m+4)` // (3)
- n=3, after (2), so we call `f1(m+3)` // (3)
- n=4, after (2), so we call `f1(m+2)` // (3)
- n=5, after (2), so we call `f1(m+1)` // (3)

We can see that `f1(m+4)` is called twice, and that we are calling `f1(m + i)` in reverse order from `i=1` to `i=4`.

We can "unfold" the function:

```
void f(int n, int m){
     f1(m + n - 1);
     for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) {
         f1(m + i);
     }
}
```

As both `m` and `n` approach infinity the `+1` or `-1` mean nothing.

The space complexity is the space complexity of `f1(max(m + i, m + n - 1))`, because `f1` frees the memory each time. So it's `(m + n - 1) * sizeof(int)` which is `(m + n) * sizeof(int)`, which is `m + n`.

The time complexity is dependent on how many times we call `f1` function. We see that we call:

```
f1(m + n - 1)
f1(m + n - 1)
f1(m + n - 2)
...
f1(m + 2)
f1(m + 1)
```

So the time complexity is

```
(m + n - 1) + ((m + n - 1) + (m + n - 2) + ... + (m + 1))
(m + n - 1) + (n - 1) * m + ((n - 1) + (n - 2) + ... 1)
(m + n - 1) + (n - 1) * m + ((n - 1) * (n - 1 + 1) / 2)
(m + n - 1) + (n - 1) * m + ((n - 1) * (n - 1 + 1) / 2)
// the `*2`, `/2`, `+1` and `-1` mean nothing close to infinity
 m + n      + n       * m + n        *  n
m + n + m * n + n * n
m * (n + 1) + n * (n + 1)
(m + n) * (n + 1)
(m + n) * n
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually a tricky question!
The second function call `f(n%2, m+1)` is just calling the recursive f once because it calculates the reminder of n to 2 which can be either 1 or 0! and in both cases the f function is returned without any further recursive call.
So it is not log n.

The function f is called once in `f(n-1, m+1)` n times and just right after that in `f(n%2, m+1)`, it will be called again once more time. It is then O(2n) if only considering n factor.

Now considering the m factor, we will notice that the loop inside the if is repeating m times and m is increasing by one at each recursive call (and actually decreasing when it returns back from the recursive call!) so it would be the sum of (m+n ... m+1) which is O(mn+n(n+1)/2). It after the simplification.

Therefore considering both factors the **time complexity** is O(2n+mn+n(n+1)/2) which is actually after simplifying equivalent to **O(nm+n^2)**.

Regarding the storage complexity: The m is incremented for the first call (m+1) which will continue for n times but the second call is not continued, so the **storage complexity** will be **O(n+m)**.